# Resume SQL Server 2008 mirroring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A SQL Server 2008 mirroring status became `SUSPENDED`.

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> 
SET PARTNER RESUME
```

This query does not resume mirroring. Please list an alternative method to get mirroring running again. Thank you.

Comment: Does the query give you an error?

Comment: yes. will post error description asap. Thank you.